# Inject HTML onto YouTube page and PERSIST

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I'm creating a Chrome extension that injects HTML onto the YouTube page.
The script works fine when it first loads but if I were to scroll it down it just disappears.

I have tried monitoring for DOM changes using MutationsObserver.
I have tried [How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)
I have tried [Make function wait until element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149431/make-function-wait-until-element-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I have tried [How to detect page navigation on YouTube and modify its appearance seamlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077641/how-to-detect-page-navigation-on-youtube-and-modify-its-appearance-seamlessly/34100952#34100952)

None of them will PERSIST the html element injected on the page.
Let me know if more details is needed.

Comment: what kind of HTML did you inject?

Comment: Youtube overwrites the container where you insert your HTML so there's nothing you can do except re-adding it, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63879868), or finding a different place in DOM that's not reset like maybe right under document.body.